# remove p paragraph from particular html page element

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="homePageBottomNewsWrapper">
    <div class="col1">
      <div class="homePage3ColsThumbPhoto">
        <p> 
          <img alt="" src="/Content/uploads/images/imgNews4.jpg">
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to remove this p elements. How can I do that with jquery?

Update:

```
$('img').unwrap();
```

Comment: https://www.google.se/search?q=jquery+remove+element+stackoverflow&oq=jquery+remove+element+stackoverflow&aqs=chrome.0.57j60j62l3.3539j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this (*if you want to remove only tags not the inner image*)-

```
$('img').unwrap();
```

- http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/

Answer (score 4):

If you want to remove just the `<p>` tag and not the `<img>` or any number of element  then do this:

```
$(".homePage3ColsThumbPhoto p")
    .html()
        .appendTo(".homePage3ColsThumbPhoto")
    .end()
    .remove();
```

If you want to remove the whole p tag and contents to can do this;

```
$(".homePage3ColsThumbPhoto p").remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".col1 p").remove(); 
 //If you want to remove all the `p` elements in col1
```

or

```
 $(".homePage3ColsThumbPhoto p").remove(); 
//If you want to remove all the `p` elements in homePage3ColsThumbPhoto
```

or

```
  $("p").remove() 
 //if you have only one `p` element
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
$(function(){
    $(".homePage3ColsThumbPhoto p").remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it

For direct child

```
$(".homePage3ColsThumbPhoto>p").remove();
```

or

`$(".homePage3ColsThumbPhoto p").remove();` // for all the descendents.